# jQuery - Count number of letters and numbers in a field

Tags: jquery, regex

I am trying to get the number of letters and numbers in a field with jQuery.

Currently I am using this code and it doesn't work:

```js
$("#sPassword1").on('input', function() {
  var fieldValue = $(this).val();
  var count = fieldValue.length;
  var countL = fieldValue.match(/([A-z])/g).length;
  var countN = fieldValue.match(/([0-9])/g).length;
  console.log(count);
  console.log(countL);
  console.log(countN);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='password' id='sPassword1' value='abc12'/>
```

What am I doing wrong? :(

Comment: i guess you are trying to get count on change event so try `$( "#sPassword1" ).on('change', function() {`

Comment: That part works perfectly. My problem is with: var countL = fieldValue.match(/([A-z])/g).length; and var countN = fieldValue.match(/([0-9])/g).length;

Comment: I converted your code to a working snippet - it works fine unless you have no letters/numbers, so you just need to handle that scenario.

Comment: Elaborating on "it doesn't work" in future may be of benefit (ie showing what error you get and in what scenario)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me, it seems like the only thing missing is handling when there are no matches - the match wouldn't return an empty array, but a null value. See the RegExp lines:

```js
$("#sPassword1").on('input', function() {
  var fieldValue = $(this).val();
  var count = fieldValue.length;
  var countL = (fieldValue.match(/([A-z])/g) || []).length;
  var countN = (fieldValue.match(/([0-9])/g) || []).length;
  console.log({ count, countL, countN, fieldValue });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="sPassword1" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You forget to control the match function return null.

```
$( "#sPassword1" ).on('input', function() {
      var fieldValue = $(this).val();
      var count = fieldValue.length;

      var match1= fieldValue.match(/([A-z])/g);
      var match2= fieldValue.match(/([0-9])/g);
      var countL = 0;
      var countN = 0;
      if ( match1 != undefined ){
        countL = match1.length;
      }
     if ( match2 != undefined ){
        countN =  match2.length;
      }

      console.log(countL + " " +countN );
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

thats it

```js
var countL = 0,
  countN = 0;
$("#sPassword1").on('input', function() {
  var fieldValue = $(this).val();
  if ((/([A-z])/g).test(fieldValue)) countL += 1;
  if ((/([0-9])/g).test(fieldValue)) countN += 1;

  console.log(countL);
  console.log(countN);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="sPassword1" type="text" value="">
```